# ASP.NET 5 Custom roles for Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication, asp.net-core

I'm building an intranet type site with ASP.NET 5 that uses Windows Authentication.  I have the authentication working, but I don't want everyone on the domain to have access to the intranet site.  I can't use domain roles so I've set up my own custom roles in my SQL Server.  I have a table that maps the domain username to roles.  I want to restrict access to the intranet site to only users that have a role defined in my SQL Server role table.  How would I set up custom roles for Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 5?  Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at SqlRoleProvider?

Comment: I don't believe SqlRoleProvider is available in ASP.NET 5.  At least I couldn't find any reference to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't set up custom roles. You need to create a custom authorization attribute, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx).

**UPDATE:**

Yes, you can use your custom authorize attribute globally. Let's say here's your custom authorize attribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // Check to see if user has a role in the database
        var isAuthorized = db.User.Find(username).Any();

        return isAuthorized;
    }
}
```

Then, you can either use it at the Action level or Controller level like this:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Or, you can register it as a global filter in your FilterConfig class under the App_Start folder, like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can a custom authorization attribute automatically run on every request?  I thought those were just to add an attribute above specific controllers like [MyCustomAttribute] to restrict users on a specific controller(s).